# Mageto 2 : getUrl returns true even the page is set to disabled

Tags: magento2, page, geturl

I created a page `testPage` and use `$pageExist = $this->getUrl('testPage') ?>` so i could render an a block if it exist like so `if ($pageExist)`

BUT when i go from amdin panel and set page from enabled to disabled, clear cache, the `$pageExist` is till true, or what i assume, since `if` statement is getting fired even tho you can not enter that URL

Comment: What do you really want to achieve with that ? I'm not getting what you want with : so i could render an a block if it exist

Answer (score 0):

getUrl() is just a return address Magento understands no matter the particular page exists or not. you should debug how magento redirects to 404 when no page found.

Check File : \Magento\Framework\App\FrontController

```
 public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('routers_match');
        $this->validatedRequest = false;
        $routingCycleCounter = 0;
        $result = null;
        while (!$request->isDispatched() && $routingCycleCounter++ < 100) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface $router */
            foreach ($this->_routerList as $router) {
                try {
                    $actionInstance = $router->match($request);
                    if ($actionInstance) {
                        $result = $this->processRequest(
                            $request,
                            $actionInstance
                        );
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException $e) {
                    $request->initForward();
                    $request->setActionName('noroute');
                    $request->setDispatched(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('routers_match');
        if ($routingCycleCounter > 100) {
            throw new \LogicException('Front controller reached 100 router match iterations');
        }
        return $result;
    }
```